# Bootstrap 4 dropdown in modal incorrect in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I added dropdown in a modal. When the dropdown opens, the height of the modal changes in Chrome, but in Firefox all is correct. 
If I delete the class modal-dialog-scrollable it starts working correctly.

**Incorrect in chrome**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu9oX.jpg]

**Correct in Firefox**

[image]

Comment: Use dev tools on both and see the difference in css ?

Comment: Yes, it looks the same, no difference noticed.

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS. This may be due to a problem with incorrectly formatted HTML and/or CSS.

Comment: Could you please add your code? It will help us help you. =)